# Having trouble with a function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have the following problem:

I don't want WP adding wpautop to all pages, but only the ones I need, so I added this:

```
function my_wpautop_correction() {
    if( is_page() ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );      
    }
    if( is_page( array(79, 81) ) ) {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );     
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_wpautop_correction');
```

Seems to be working fine, but I am not sure if its the best way to write that function. I've tried this:

```
function my_wpautop_correction() {
    if( !( is_page(79) || is_page(81) ) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );      
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_wpautop_correction');
```

But it doesnt work, what I am doing wrong? I want to add wpautop only to pages 79 and 81.

Comment: If you want to remove pages 79, 81, why do you call add_filter on them in the working function?

Comment: Oops sorry, noticed my wording was wrong. I want to add wpautop only to pages 79 and 81, and remove it from all other pages. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Using an `array()` is cleaner than checking individual pages, and [the function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) can accept arrays.

Comment: But is the first code written ok? I don't know php, I just hack it through to make it work :P So far that works, but I think there is a better way to write that if.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function my_wpautop_correction() {
    if( !is_page(79) || !is_page(81) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );      
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_wpautop_correction');
```

Comment: Nope, it removes the filter from all the pages.

Comment: You will need to please provide the rest of the code to help you